# How can I get the network time in flutter app without internet connectivity?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am developing time based application in flutter, How can I use network time without internet connectivity or How can I track the modified system time in mobile application?

Comment: If there is no network then you can't get time from the network. If people have put their clock forward you can't really detect it, but if time goes backwards you can track it simply by periodically storing the current time and comparing to see if time has gone backwards

Comment: Do we have any option to track the time setup? Automatic/Manual in flutter?

Comment: No.  Essentially you cannot trust device time. You can only trust time you get from an external source